# Java regex To find start of string

Tags: java, regex

Could you please help me with following as I do not want to waist any more time on it;

I have following code which is not working;

```
String someStr = "C:\SomeDir";
boolean = someStr.matches("(^[A-Z|a-z]:[\\\\:/])*"));
```

The above code is returning **false**, but it I think it should return 'true', am I missing anything? I just want to know if my string starts with C:\ or C:/ or :[/|]....

Thanks,

--

SJunejo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match is only true for an *exact match*  as documented.

What you appear to want is

```
boolean root = someStr.matches("[A-Za-z]:[\\\\/].*");
```

Comment: How about this, this is also not working?
String UUID = "ac3b8a82-ae68-4ad0-b8ec-77032d457f74";
String matcher = "[\\w-{8}{4}{4}{4}\\w{12}]";
System.out.println("Matches = " + UUID.matches(matcher));

Comment: @SJunejo I would break down what you are doing, `-{8}{4}{4}{4}` is the same as 8 * 4 * 4 * 4 which is 512 dashes